# $C^*$ algebra of LCA-group

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, c-star-algebras

I'm reading A. Deitmar and S. Echterhoff's book "Principles of Harmonic Analysis", and have a confusion of the proof in the snapshot: Why do we need to prove $\|f\|\equiv\|f\eta\|$ in order to show $m$ is a continuous map? I think that the proof closes as soon as we have $|m(f)|\le\|f\chi\bar{\chi_0}\|$

Note that $L$ is an inclusion from $L^1(A)$ to $B(L^2(A))$ given by $\langle L(f)\phi,\psi\rangle=\int_A f(y)\langle L_y\phi,\psi\rangle dy$

[image: A snapshot of the book]

Comment: More often than not, when you post an image in order to ask a question, the reader is left scrambling for the definitions of the symbols involved.  In the present case your image fails to include a definition of $L$ and, while you gave that definition below the image, I bet most readers will likely waste a lot of time looking for it.

Comment: I have rearranged my question, is the format appropriate now? The confusion is that I understand that we need to prove $m$ is continuous in the $C^*$ norm, but it just derives from the estimate $|m(f)|\le \|f\chi\bar{\chi_0}$, so I don't know what the author is doing in the following paragraphs.

Comment: Does $\chi\bar{\chi_0}\in C^*(A)$? Otherwise it is not clear why just the inequality $|m(f)|\le \|f\chi\bar{\chi_0}\|$ implies m is continuous. He proves after the denoted paragraph that in fact  $\|f\chi\bar{\chi_0}\|=\|f\|$.

Comment: You are right! The continuity is very clear as soon as$|m(f)|\le \|f\|$ is proven. I just thought of $\|\chi\bar{\chi_0}\|=1$ as trivial, which is somehow not.